# Bash Post Increment

Tags: bash, post-increment

Just a little question about the right way of doing Post-increment in bash.

```
while true; do
  VAR=$((CONT++))
  echo "CONT: $CONT"
  sleep 1
done
```

VAR starts at 1 in this case.

```
CONT: 1
CONT: 2
CONT: 3
```

But if I do this:

```
while true; do
  echo "CONT: $((CONT++))"
  sleep 1
done
```

It starts at 0.

```
CONT: 0
CONT: 1
CONT: 2
```

Seems that the the first case is behaving ok, because ((CONT++)) would evaluate CONT (undefined,¿0?) and add +1.

How can I get a behaviour like in `echo` statement to assign to a variable?

EDIT: In my first example, instead of echoing CONT, I should have echoed VAR, that way it works OK, so it was my error from the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**both** cases are OK and reasonable.

`foo++` will first return current value (before auto-incrementing) of `foo`, then auto-increment.

in your 1st case, if you change into `echo "CONT: $VAR"`, it will give same result as case 2.

If you want to have `1,2,3...`, with auto-increment, you could try:

```
echo "CONT: $((++CONT))"
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it, but I would like to do it in the assignment to a variable, not in an echo. In an echo it works OK, but not when I assign to variable (I dont know the right way to start from 0).

Comment: I just noticed that it works good and was my error in the first example, instead of echoing VAR, I echoed CONT. Thats why it wasnt working.

Comment: @Jorge your first case (`$VAR`) is starting from 0

Comment: Remember, though, that if you use something like `declare -i counter=0`, then `counter` will be an integer instead of a string. Thus, using `$((counter++))` is no longer necessary to perform arithmetic. `((counter++))` will do.

Comment: So, if I have the command `echo $((age++))` for example, then does that mean command substitution has higher precedence than post increment?

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your code to make it easier to understand.

The following:

```
  VAR=$((CONT++))
  echo "CONT: $CONT"
```

can be broken down into the following steps:

```
  VAR=$CONT            # assign CONT to VAR
  CONT=$((CONT+1))     # increment CONT
  echo "CONT: $CONT"   # print CONT
```

Similary, the following the statement:

```
echo "CONT: $((CONT++))"
```

is equivalent to:

```
echo "CONT: $CONT"    # print CONT
CONT=$((CONT+1))      # then increment CONT
```

Hope this helps explain why you see that behaviour.

Comment: I just noticed that it works good and was my error in the first example, instead of echoing VAR, I echoed CONT. Thats why it wasnt working.

Answer (score 1):

Post increment means, return the *previous* value and then increment the value.

In your first example, you use the value *after* it was incremented. In your second example you use it *before* you increment it.

If you want the same result as in the first example, you must use prefix increment

```
while true; do
    echo "CONT: $((++CONT))"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it, but I would like to do it in the assignment to a variable, not in an echo. In an echo it works OK, but not when I assign to variable (I dont know the right way to start from 0).

Comment: I just noticed that it works good and was my error in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

`((CONT++))` is what increments the variable. Adding the `"$"` is for other purposes.