# Bash post increment inside expression

Tags: bash

Consider the following script.

```
i=1
echo $(printf "%02d" $i)
((i++))
echo $(printf "%02d" $i)
```

The output is:

```
01
02
```

I would like to remove the line in the `((i++))` line in the middle, and have something like the following, but it just prints `01` twice.

```
i=1
echo $(printf "%02d" $((i++)))
echo $(printf "%02d" $i)
```

**How can I get the same output of `01` followed by `02` without a separate statement to do the increment?**

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025564/bash-post-increment), and the solution there does not work for this use case.

**Update**: I am running in a subshell because the real problem is to do variable assignment:

```
x=$(printf "%02d" $((i++)))
```

I changed it to `echo` originally to simplify the example.

Comment: It works if you skip the `printf`. Not sure whether that's an option for you.

Comment: @RSahu, No, that unfortunately is not an option for me

Comment: Any changes to the variable while in a subshell is only valid for that subshell. You have no other choice but to increment while in the parent shell. However, if the incremented value is only needed for printing but not needed later, then you can just change the second statement and use pre-increment or use `i+1`.

Comment: @alvits, Is it possible to get the output of a command into a variable *without* using a subshell?

Comment: Yes it is possible using bash builtin printf. `printf -v x "%02d" $i` will assign the value of `$i` to `$x`. So in your case it will be `printf -v x "%02d" $((i++))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to assign value of a variable without resorting to subshell by using bash builtin printf.

In your case, you want to increment `i` while executing the 1st statement then use the same variable on the second statement.

Here's how you do it using bash builtin printf.

```
i=1
printf -v x "%02d" $((i++))
printf -v y "%02d" $i
```

You will end up with `x=01` and `y=02`.

Comment: So, if I have the command `echo $((age++))` for example, then does that mean command substitution has higher precedence than post increment?